# Is it mandatory initialize "sub-objects" when use JSF?

Tags: jsf, el

I have a class called `Customer` and another called `Person`. The class `Customer` has a property `Person`, see the code bellow;

```
public class Customer{

   private String name;
   private Person person;
}
```

But when I try to use the `#{customerManagedBean.customer.person.id}` I got a error because I can't reach the property id from person, because person is null.

So I changed my code to:

```
public Class Customer{

   public Customer{
   person = new Person();
   }

   private String name;
   private Person person;
}
```

And everything works fine. Is it mandatory initialize all objects inside my class before using it?

Comment: Your question is about basic Java. If you never initialize a field of your class, it will take the default value, if it's an object the default value is `null`.

Comment: Good explains from everybody. But initialize a nested property in constructor is a good practice ?

Comment: It depends on the design. IMO if is just an entity declared in your managed bean, you should initialize it in a `@PostConstruct` method inside your `CustomerManagedBean`, and when initializing the `Customer` (probably with a service class and method) this should consider setting the `Person` value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll use @PostConstruct as solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. The setter method is only invoked on the final property, which is `id`. JSF, or more specifically, [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), won't autocreate nested properties for you. The model (the backing bean) is responsible for that. You should in fact create `Person` in `CustomerManagedBean` class, not in `Customer` class.

That it works for managed beans is simply because those managed beans are via `@ManagedBean` or `@Named` explicitly registered to be auto-created when they do not exist in the EL scope yet. This does in turn not apply to their nested properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Initialize the `Person` instance along with `Customer` instance in `CustomerManagedBean`'s `Constructor` or `@PostConstruct` methods